# Why is the angular Datatable not rendering?

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I am new to Angular Datatables.
How can I re-render the datatable, if it is hidden previously?

I have two components, Parent and child both hiding and showing through button clicks based on a flag.

**Expected:**
If a new row is added through child component, I need to re-render the table.(code not written for adding new row but an emitter is applied.) Kindly help

**Problem:**
On adding new row from child component, all rows are shown, datatabble not rendered.

**Parent HTML**

```
    <div [hidden]="!showlist">
    <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>completed</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let user of todo">
                <td> {{t.id}} </td>
                <td> {{t.title}} </td>
                <td> {{t.completed}} </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a class="btn btn-default">
            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="showChild()">ShowChild</button>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


<hr>
<div *ngIf="!showlist">
    <app-child (back)="showParent()" (rowAdded)="todo()">
    </app-child>
</div>
```

**Parent ts**

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  todo: Array<any>;
  showlist: boolean;   
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.todo();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }

  apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";

  todo() {
    this.showlist = true;
    this.dtTrigger = new Subject();
    this.dtTrigger.subscribe();
    this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data => {
      this.todo= data;
      this.dtTrigger.next();
      this.ngOnDestroy();
    });
  }
  showChild() {
    this.showlist = false;
  }

  showParent() {
    this.showlist = true;
  }
}
```

**Child HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-default" (click)="addRow()">Add row</button> &nbsp;
<button class="btn btn-default" (click)="showParent()">ShowParent</button>
```

**Child ts**

```
  export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() rowAdded: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() back: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  addRow() {
    //code to add new row
    this.rowAdded.emit();
  }
  showParent() {
    this.back.emit();
  }
}
```

**ALSO VIEW:**
[STACKBLITZ DEMO CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatable-20180726-k6jepz?file=app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is your variables name. They are the same.

- `todo: Array<any>;`
- `todo()`

Please rename one of both. And try again.

Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatable-20180726-xs4dhg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) on stackblitz

**Edit**

After fix naming issue.

```js
todo() {
    this.showlist = true;
    this.dtTrigger = new Subject();
    this.dtTrigger.subscribe();
    this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.todoList = data;
      this.dtTrigger.next();
      // remove unsubscribe after get all data.
    });
  }
```

**Why this happened?**

According with [angular-datatables source code](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/blob/master/src/angular-datatables.directive.ts#L44). Each time you call emit new value with `dtTrigger` subject. This call a internal function named `this.displayTable();`

dtTrigger comment

> This trigger is used if one wants to trigger manually the DT rendering
>
> - Useful when rendering angular rendered DOM

If you unsubscribe after get data. Table go away.

Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatable-20180726-xs4dhg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) on stackblitz

**Edit 2**

It looks like there is an issue with render table. It has rewrite all table and trigger [this issue](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3)

Following I have detroying instance of data table and recreate new one.

Possible [issue is on this line](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/blob/master/src/angular-datatables.directive.ts#L96)

[Here is the working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatable-20180726-xs4dhg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: sorry but your example is also not working! On click of addrow button on child component , Datatable loses its original form.. all rows are shown.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I have updated my answer

Comment: really appreciate your effort, but still same issue prevails.. if you click on add row button (in your working example) all the rows are visible (only 10 rows with pagination should be visible as was on initial load), table loses its original format.. I.e not rendered correctly...kindly help

Comment: I'm sorry, I had tested again. Please check out the working example again. And Edit 2

Answer (score 0):

call `this.dtTrigger.next();` inside `ngAfterViewInit(){}`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.